# How to get current customer id magento rest api

Tags: php, magento, rest

I want to use magento rest api authorization for my web application customers, I found in docs that there is `/customers/:customerId` request, to get information about user, but I can't understand, how to get `customerId` to make this request. Is there such a method in Magento REST API and if not, how I can get authorized customer Id via REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a REST service to get a list of all existing customers and their customerId. Its a GET request to /customers. You can find its description in the REST API docs http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html#RESTAPI-Resource-Customers-HTTPMethod-GET-customers

Unfortunately there is no service to authenticate users using username and password that I know of. Not even in the SOAP API that has much more services than the REST API.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I use magento REST OAuth 1 authorization. And my customers are logged in with "customer" role, but /customers request is available only for admin. Even if it was available for customer, I still don't understand how I can get current customer id.

Comment: I dug trough the Magneto OAuth code and didn't find any way to get the current customer ID, sorry. But the authentication system knows about current customer Id, and it is saved in userParams object as ID attribute (...Auth/Adapter/Oauth.php), so you could extend REST service and return current customer ID. And thanks, now I know a lot about Magento REST OAuth :)

Comment: Thanks, it seems I need to add some kind of '/me' REST method to get info about current logged in user